# Can someone formulate John Pollack's argument in understandable terms for laymen?

Tags: theology, proof, ontological-argument, existence-of-god

http://www.strongatheism.net/library/atheology/ontological_argument_for_nonexistence/

By the way, I am not asking whether this argument is sound or not. I just want to have it formulated in understandable terms for laymen.

From what I have been told the argument is basically saying that

> If God (maximally perfect being which none greater can be conceived)exists, God necessarily exists.
>
> Something necessarily exists only if it is logically necessary.
>
> God is not logically necessary because something is logically
> necessary only if its existence follows logically from its definition,
> and the existence of God does not follow logically from its
> definition.
>
> So, God does not exist.

Why does the definition of God by Pollack not follow logically from its definition? THIS IS IMPORTANT BECAUSE THIS IS WHERE UPON THE WHOLE ARGUMENT RESTS THAT GOD IS NOT LOGICALLY NECESSARY.

Comment: The copy-and-paste left a lot of the notation messed up, so this was hard to follow, but I think your summary of the argument is accurate. It was odd to read this argument because I always took it the opposite way: that the claim "if God exists then he exists necessarily" implies that there is a form of necessity that is not logical necessity. Instead, this argument assumes that there is only logical necessity and from that refutes the claim.

Comment: Clean up the quote and post again. Note the duplicate text beginning, “Here we have taken’Px’”. Divide the long quote into readable pieces.

Comment: @David Gudeman,do you know why the existence of God doesn't follow from its definition in this argument?

Comment: @Mark Andrews,I linked to a page with the argument.

Comment: Much more accessible. Thank you.

Comment: @BernardEakins, yes, because nothing follows from a definition. Except the definition itself.

Comment: @DavidGudeman,so that means God's existance  is not logically necessary and thus in the author's view his nonexistance is necessary?and why does nothing follow from a definition?Sorry I'm a layman trying to understand this argument precisely.

Comment: The premise says that (A) if God exists, he exists necessarily. The argument then claims that (B) the only form of necessity is logical necessity, and from (B) argues that (C) God's existence is not necessary. Then (A) and (C) imply that God does not exist. However, anyone who would defend (A) would reject (B), so there is no path to (C). (A) is based on the notion of metaphysical necessity, not logical necessity.